# Link the site with text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to link text with a site and do not know what the problem is. This is the program, this site examines the feelings in the text:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import parse



text= ("i hate you ")
i=parse.quote(text)
API_Call=urlopen( 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/classify?text= '+ i )
f=json.loads(API_Call.read())
print (f)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], you don't even say why you think there is a problem.

Comment: I do not know what exactly the problem is
What I want to do is to insert a sentence and examine it using the site but by Python
I do not know what the problem is in linking the text with the site in the program   http://www.sentiment140.com/api/classify?text=new+moon+is+awesome

Comment: Again, *why do you think there **is** a problem?* What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Please read the above-linked guidance. You might not know where the problem is, but surely there is a reason you're asking this question?

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and figured out that the problem you're facing is that the `urlopen` method is giving you a Bad Request exception. This is because you have a unescaped space in the url. Remove the space and you'll get the expected output.

Change `API_Call=urlopen( 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/classify?text= '+ i )` to `API_Call=urlopen( 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/classify?text='+ i )` (Removed space after `text=`)for getting the expected output.

PS: Next time when you post a question, include the full stack trace for others to figure out the issue.